# Função jQuery não funciona

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou fazendo uma função com jQuery, mas não funciona, ou seja, não chega na minha controller, alguem poderia me ajudar por favor, segue o código:

```
var Aprovar = function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'GerenciaPassagem/AprovarPassagem',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ mes: $("#ListaPeriodo").val() }),
        success: function (data) {
            $("#tabFiltra").html(data);
            drawTable();
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.blockUI({ message: '<img src="' + url + '/Content/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Aguardando..."/>' });
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.unblockUI();
        },
        error: function (a, b, c) {
            var x = a;
        }
    });
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="button" value="Aprovar" id="btAprovar" onclick="listaPassagens(); return false;" style="margin-left: 9px;" /> @*onclick="Aprovar(); return false;"*@
```

Comment: Seu botão não chama a função `Aprovar`, e sim `listaPassagens`.

Comment: Leu o comentário do bfavaretto? pode responder e se necessário juntar o código da função `listaPassagens();`

Comment: Adiciona o seu Controller com esse ActionResult

Comment: Esse post já foi solucionado? @user7566 ???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se eu bem entendi, o que você quer fazer é chamar aquela função ao clicar no botão correto?

Se sim o código ficará assim:

troque `var Aprovar = function () {`

por: `function listaPassagens(){ /* Nome que você já utilizou */`

No botão terá que ter isso:

```
<intput type="button" onclick="javascript: listaPassagens();"
```

ou adicione a linha no seu js e retire as chamadas do botão:

```
$("#btAprovar").click( function(){ listaPassagens() } );
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Sua última linha está incorreta, você não pode chamar `listaPassagens`

Comment: Caso crie a função como citei acima: "function listaPassagens()" pode sim... adicionei um function na chamada pois não testei o código.

Comment: Com a sua alteração sim, funciona. Da outra forma garanto que não.

Comment: Obrigado pela correção @bfavaretto realmente não tinha prestado atenção

Comment: Esse post já foi solucionado? @user7566 ???

Comment: Funcionou obrigado

Comment: A função `listaPassagens` pode ser passada diretamente para o click, apenas para evitar a criação de mais uma função: `$("#btAprovar").click(listaPassagens);` :)